# High availability - Spring Boot docker application based on external event that persist data to a database

Tags: spring-boot, events, high-availability

I have created an app with spring boot that listen to events and persist event data to a MySQL.

I have deployed the app into a server with docker and docker-swarm.

And now I need that this spring boot event app has high availability.

The problem is that if I scale the service to multiples replicas, then each replica will receive each new event and duplicate the data in the database as they share the same database.

So, how should I approach this?